# I am getting the error of Index Out of Bound Exception and Toast message is not coming

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

Here is my code where I set count value to -1. and I gave count<10 only for next button. And count>=0 for prev button. And also else statement(Toast message) is not working. Kindly please help me to solve this error.

```
public class story extends AppCompatActivity {
Button next;
Button prev;
TextView t;
int count=-1;
int[] stories = {
        R.string.firststory,
        R.string.story2,
        R.string.story3,
        R.string.story4,
        R.string.story5,
        R.string.story6,
        R.string.story7,
        R.string.story8,
        R.string.story9,
        R.string.story10,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.story);

    next = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.next);
    prev = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    t = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(stories[0])));
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            count=count+1;
            try{
            if(count<10) {
                t.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(stories[count])));
            }
                else{
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is Last story",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    });
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            count=count-1;
            try{
            if(count>=0)
            {
            t.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(stories[count])));
            }
            else{
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is first story",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: please provide the logcat error

Comment: the toast isn't showing because you never call toast.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think what would happen if the user presses the `next` button too many times - `count` will be higher than 10 (say 12). Now the user presses the `prev` button. `count` will be 11, and the condition is `TRUE` - it's bigger than 0, so you will try to access the 11th item on your array.
You must not increase the value of counter too much:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        try{
        if(count<10) {
            count=count+1;
            t.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(stories[count])));
        } else {...
```

Move the `count = count + 1` inside the condition. That way it won't exceed it's limit.
Do the same for the second button.
And for the `Toast` - you never call the `.show()` method.

Comment: But even it positive exceeds or negative exceeds in the count, I written the condition, So, It will not go inside right?

Comment: Did you try my solution? Your condition is only half right - if you've pressed the `next` button too many times and `count = 12` then the condition is good and the toast will be displayed, but when you'll press `prev` count will be decreamented to 11, the condition `count >=0` is true and your program will try to access the 11th item on the array and will crash. Do as I wrote - increase and decrease the counter **after** the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

First, the toast:

To display a toast message you need call the "show()" method. Try adding the following line after you create your toast:

```
toast.show();
```

Second, the index:

You are probably acessing your array with a value greater than 9 or lesser than 0. You should use the debugger (or insert a log message if you are not comfortable with the debugger) to check the value of the "count" variable just before you access the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are omitting the exception occurred in the try block. Please print it using `e.printStackTrace()`, so that you can know the exact error and the line at which it is occurring.

and for Toast, as others have mentioned, use `show()` to display it.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is first story",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

or directly,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is first story",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```